# how can I add movable images to my GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to add an image which can move like when you sign in,you will see an image of yahoo messenger that moves suddenly.
thanks

** I also work with NetBeans**

Comment: OK, let's start at the beginning. Do you know how to load and display an image?

Comment: Moves HOW?   When the user moves the mouse?  Shake the current application window?  Something like a taskbar popup (windows)?

Comment: @ BobMcGee:like your yahoo messenger frame.at first before signing in,you will see an image which shows that image is sleeping ,please see your sign in frame for yahoo messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Put a *.gif (or a running image) in the icon of desired component, say button. Use setIcon().

Comment: If I use netbeans what should I do?

Comment: Netbeans properties window has Icon property. Set the image there.